# Angular $timeout goes into tight loop on broadcast from event handler

Tags: angularjs

I have a code structure like the following

```
service A: {
 if(/*some condition*/){
   $rootScope.$broadcast('EventX')
 }
}

service B:{
 function poll(){
   $timeout(poll, 10000);
 }
 function handler(){
   $rootScope.$broadcast('EventY');
 }
 $rootScope.$on('EventX', handler);
}
```

Once the **`EventY`** is broadcasted, the `poll` timeout runs into a tight loop. Please let me know if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: because you did it, once poll get call it will run infinite loop..i don't see any code dependency on `$braodcast`

Comment: I'm not concerned about the poll called in infinite loop. My problem is until the EventY is broadcasted, poll is called at 10 sec interval. But once EventY is broadcasted, poll runs into a tight loop, getting called without any delay.

Comment: can you please reproduce the problem with plukr or fiddle